# Stopping/Starting a remote Windows service and waiting for it to open/close

Tags: windows, windows-services

The top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187836/how-do-i-restart-a-service-on-a-remote-machine-in-windows) tells me how to stop/start a remote service. Great.
Now, all I need is to wait for the actual stop/start to complete. So, what I'm looking for is a dos command to:

1. Start a service, should return only after the service is started (or after a timeout, raising error level)
2. Stop a service, return only after the service is stopped

Comment: I'd love to know this myself.  I don't believe that it is possible with the SC command, which is asynchronous by nature.  You might have to tie that command to pings of the service status as it changes from STOPPING to STOPPED and from STARTING to STARTED.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I created a set of batch scripts that use sc.exe to do just this. They are attached below. To run these scripts, **you should be a user with administration rights on the target machine and running this from a computer that is a member of the same domain**. It's possible to set it up to be able to run from outside of the domain (like from a VPN) but there are a lot of layers of security to work through involving firewalls, DCOM and security credentials.

One of these days, I'm going to figure out the PowerShell equivalent, which should be much easier.

### safeServiceStart.bat

```
@echo off
:: This script originally authored by Eric Falsken

IF [%1]==[] GOTO usage
IF [%2]==[] GOTO usage

ping -n 1 %1 | FIND "TTL=" >NUL
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO SystemOffline
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" >NUL
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO SystemOffline

:ResolveInitialState
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "STOPPED" >NUL
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO StartService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "RUNNING" >NUL
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO StartedService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "PAUSED" >NUL
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO SystemOffline
echo Service State is changing, waiting for service to resolve its state before making changes
sc \\%1 query %2 | Find "STATE"
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
GOTO ResolveInitialState

:StartService
echo Starting %2 on \\%1
sc \\%1 start %2 >NUL

GOTO StartingService
:StartingServiceDelay
echo Waiting for %2 to start
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
:StartingService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "RUNNING" >NUL
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO StartingServiceDelay

:StartedService
echo %2 on \\%1 is started
GOTO:eof

:SystemOffline
echo Server \\%1 is not accessible or is offline
GOTO:eof

:usage
echo %0 [system name] [service name]
echo Example: %0 server1 MyService
echo.
GOTO:eof
```

### safeServiceStop.bat

```
@echo off
:: This script originally authored by Eric Falsken

IF [%1]==[] GOTO usage
IF [%2]==[] GOTO usage

ping -n 1 %1 | FIND "TTL=" >NUL
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO SystemOffline
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" >NUL
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO SystemOffline

:ResolveInitialState
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "RUNNING" >NUL
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO StopService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "STOPPED" >NUL
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO StopedService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "PAUSED" >NUL
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO SystemOffline
echo Service State is changing, waiting for service to resolve its state before making changes
sc \\%1 query %2 | Find "STATE"
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
GOTO ResolveInitialState

:StopService
echo Stopping %2 on \\%1
sc \\%1 stop %2 %3 >NUL

GOTO StopingService
:StopingServiceDelay
echo Waiting for %2 to stop
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
:StopingService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "STOPPED" >NUL
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO StopingServiceDelay

:StopedService
echo %2 on \\%1 is stopped
GOTO:eof

:SystemOffline
echo Server \\%1 or service %2 is not accessible or is offline
GOTO:eof

:usage
echo Will cause a remote service to STOP (if not already stopped).
echo This script will waiting for the service to enter the stopped state if necessary.
echo.
echo %0 [system name] [service name] {reason}
echo Example: %0 server1 MyService
echo.
echo For reason codes, run "sc stop"
GOTO:eof
```

### safeServiceRestart.bat

```
@echo off
:: This script originally authored by Eric Falsken

if [%1]==[] GOTO usage
if [%2]==[] GOTO usage

ping -n 1 %1 | FIND "TTL=" >NUL
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO SystemOffline
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" >NUL
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO SystemOffline

:ResolveInitialState
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "RUNNING" >NUL
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO StopService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "STOPPED" >NUL
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO StartService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "PAUSED" >NUL
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO SystemOffline
echo Service State is changing, waiting for service to resolve its state before making changes
sc \\%1 query %2 | Find "STATE"
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
GOTO ResolveInitialState

:StopService
echo Stopping %2 on \\%1
sc \\%1 stop %2 %3 >NUL

GOTO StopingService
:StopingServiceDelay
echo Waiting for %2 to stop
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
:StopingService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "STOPPED" >NUL
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO StopingServiceDelay

:StopedService
echo %2 on \\%1 is stopped
GOTO StartService

:StartService
echo Starting %2 on \\%1
sc \\%1 start %2 >NUL

GOTO StartingService
:StartingServiceDelay
echo Waiting for %2 to start
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
:StartingService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "RUNNING" >NUL
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO StartingServiceDelay

:StartedService
echo %2 on \\%1 is started
GOTO:eof

:SystemOffline
echo Server \\%1 or service %2 is not accessible or is offline
GOTO:eof

:usage
echo Will restart a remote service, waiting for the service to stop/start (if necessary)
echo.
echo %0 [system name] [service name] {reason}
echo Example: %0 server1 MyService
echo.
echo For reason codes, run "sc stop"
GOTO:eof
```

Comment: Note that the timeout command is only available in Vista and Server 2003 (and newer). On Windows XP, use the SLEEP command found in the NT Resource Kit. (Thanks James)

Comment: Also note that the ping command to check for the availability of the server assumes that the server is on IPv4. Probably would be better to include the '-4' switch to force ping to use IPv4.

Comment: Kudos for useful scripts! Note that if you have some other FIND command in your path, e.g. a Unix `find` from cygwin, it'll trip this script up.

Comment: I wish I had more than one upvote to give. This is brilliant.

Comment: @EricFalsken - the "system is offline" detection bit in your (otherwise awesome) scripts has issues with ipv6 addresses as ping does not print out TTL for ipv6 addresses. adding -4 forces ipv4 ping, but thats not always possible to do

Comment: Great script! I found that I did need the ping -4 and replacing timeout with ping as suggested below. Additionally, I think it is better to remove the >NULL for the sc start/stop command so you can actually see any exception messages. I also added "IF errorlevel 1 EXIT 1" there so that the script stops on errors such as access denied instead of waiting forever.

Comment: Any version in Powershell ?

Comment: Thanks for the script. I'm seeing the sc query take a long time in our environment. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't get why you can't just do net stop <service>\n ping 127.0.0.1 -n <seconds>\n net start <service> and put that in a bat script and schedule it via scheduler?

Comment: @Nik, it's because a ping is insufficient to know whether the server is online, and sometimes servers take seconds or long minutes to come back online depending on why they are rebooting. A simple `-n <seconds>` will ping for that long, and not just until it gets a response. What if the server doesn't come up within your `n seconds`, or if it is already up, why wait?

Comment: @Eric you miss the point of ping above completely, it mimics sleep function, which bat does not have, not query status. Look at address it is pinging

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes, bat has the `timeout` command that serves that purpose. The difference is that this script will continue retrying until it sees that both the target computer is online AND that the service is stopped. Sure, `net stop service` will work for most people who want to stop a service, but this script is for when you *really* want it to stop, make sure it is stopped, and wait for it to stop until it really is stopped. `net stop service` will send the stop command but if the service cannot stop, or takes a while, files could still be in use when the script continues.

Comment: I'd like the script can handle timeout as well, example: `safeServiceStop.bat 192.168.1.10 ServiceB -t 60` will run the script for 60s only. Currently, if some ServiceA depends on ServiceB, the script file will run forever

Answer (score 10):

What about powershell and WaitForStatus? Eg, the script below would restart SQL Server on a remote machine:

```
$computer = "COMPUTER_NAME"
$me = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "DOMAIN\user", (convertto-securestring "password" -asplaintext -force)
$restartSqlServer = { 
    $sqlServer = get-service mssqlserver
    $waitInterval = new-timespan -seconds 5
    if (-not ($sqlServer.Status -eq "Stopped")) {
        $sqlServer.Stop()
        $sqlServer.WaitForStatus('Stopped', $waitInterval) 
    }
    $sqlServer.Start()
    $sqlServer.WaitForStatus('Running', $waitInterval) 
}     
icm -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock $restartSqlServer -Credential $me
```

Comment: How do you call it? I have forgotten more than I remember about powershell.

Comment: @JustEngland - just putting the code into a file with ".ps1" extension and running it from Poweshell console or ISE should do the job.

Answer (score 8):

I've never actually seen something that does this specifically but it would be quite easy to knock such a utility out in C\C#\VB or any other language that gives easy access to the Service API. Here's a sample of something in C#.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace SCSync
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;

        private const int ERROR_INVALID_COMMAND_LINE = 1;
        private const int ERROR_NO_ACCESS = 2;
        private const int ERROR_COMMAND_TIMEOUT = 3;
        private const int ERROR_NO_SERVICE = 4;
        private const int ERROR_NO_SERVER = 5;
        private const int ERROR_INVALID_STATE = 6;
        private const int ERROR_UNSPECIFIED = 7;

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (args.Length < 2 || args.Length > 4)
            {
                ShowUsage();
                return ERROR_INVALID_COMMAND_LINE;
            }

            string serviceName = args[0];
            string command = args[1].ToUpper();
            string serverName = ".";
            string timeoutString = "30";
            int timeout;

            if (args.Length > 2)
            {
                if (args[2].StartsWith(@"\\"))
                {
                    serverName = args[2].Substring(2);
                    if (args.Length > 3)
                    {
                        timeoutString = args[3];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    timeoutString = args[2];
                }
            }

            if (!int.TryParse(timeoutString, out timeout))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid timeout value.\n");
                ShowUsage();
                return ERROR_INVALID_COMMAND_LINE;
            }

            try
            {
                ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceName, serverName);
                switch (command)
                {
                    case "START":
                        sc.Start();
                        sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, timeout));
                        break;
                    case "STOP":
                        sc.Stop();
                        sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, timeout));
                        break;
                    case "PAUSE":
                        sc.Pause();
                        sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Paused, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, timeout));
                        break;
                    case "CONTINUE":
                        sc.Continue();
                        sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, timeout));
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid command value.\n");
                        ShowUsage();
                        return ERROR_INVALID_COMMAND_LINE;
                }
            }
            catch (System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Operation timed out.\n");
                return ERROR_COMMAND_TIMEOUT;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are not authorized to perform this action.\n");
                return ERROR_NO_ACCESS;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException opEx)
            {
                Win32Exception winEx = opEx.InnerException as Win32Exception;
                if (winEx != null)
                {
                    switch (winEx.NativeErrorCode)
                    {
                        case 5: //ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
                            Console.WriteLine("You are not authorized to perform this action.\n");
                            return ERROR_NO_ACCESS;
                        case 1722: //RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE
                            Console.WriteLine("The server is unavailable or does not exist.\n");
                            return ERROR_NO_SERVER;
                        case 1060: //ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
                            Console.WriteLine("The service does not exist.\n");
                            return ERROR_NO_SERVICE;
                        case 1056: //ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING
                            Console.WriteLine("The service is already running.\n");
                            return ERROR_INVALID_STATE;
                        case 1062: //ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE
                            Console.WriteLine("The service is not running.\n");
                            return ERROR_INVALID_STATE;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(opEx.ToString());
                return ERROR_UNSPECIFIED;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return ERROR_UNSPECIFIED;
            }

            return ERROR_SUCCESS;
        }

        private static void ShowUsage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SCSync usage:\n");
            Console.WriteLine("SCSync.exe service command <server> <timeout>\n");
            Console.WriteLine("    service   The name of the service upon which the command will act. (Required)");
            Console.WriteLine("    command   The command to execute - one of: start|stop|pause|continue. (Required)");
            Console.WriteLine("    server    The name of the server on which the target service runs. This must start with \\. (Optional)");
            Console.WriteLine("    timeout   The timeout period in seconds in which the command should finish. The default is 30 seconds. (Optional)");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The WaitForStatus is just a polling loop and could be easily replaced in any other language. The rest is just OpenService and ControlService.

Answer (score 7):

Eric Falsken's solution works perfectly. +1.

But I'd like to add that the timeout command would sometimes fail with error:
"Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately"

To fix this I've had to replace the timeout command:

```
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
```

with the following:

```
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1  1>NUL
```

Answer (score 5):

Edit on 10/20/2011 - updated my code. I posted it before fully debugging. 
Many thanks to Eric Falsken. What a great solution. I tweaked Eric's code (BTW look for a couple of typographical errors if you intend to use it). I added logging and some additional error-checking for some conditions Eric didn't account for. Since I'm most interested in a service restart (not just stopping and/or starting), I only built upon Eric's restart code. Anyway, I'm posting my version, hope you like it!

```
@ECHO off
:: This script originally authored by Eric Falsken http://stackoverflow.com/
:: Revised for by George Perkins 10/20/2011
IF [%1]==[] GOTO Usage
IF [%2]==[] GOTO Usage

:SetLocalVariables
SET /A MyDelay=0 
SET MyHours=%time:~0,2%
IF %MyHours%==0 SET MyHours=00
IF %MyHours%==1 SET MyHours=01
IF %MyHours%==2 SET MyHours=02
IF %MyHours%==3 SET MyHours=03
IF %MyHours%==4 SET MyHours=04
IF %MyHours%==5 SET MyHours=05
IF %MyHours%==6 SET MyHours=06
IF %MyHours%==7 SET MyHours=07
IF %MyHours%==8 SET MyHours=08
IF %MyHours%==9 SET MyHours=09
SET MyMinutes=%time:~3,2%
SET MySeconds=%time:~6,2%
SET MyHundredths=%time:~9,2%
SET MyMonth=%date:~4,2%
SET MyDay=%date:~-7,2%
SET MyCentury=%date:~-4,4%
SET MyTimeStamp=%MyCentury%%MyMonth%%MyDay%%MyHours%%MyMinutes%%MySeconds%
IF "%3" == "" (
         SET MyLog=C:\Temp
   ) ELSE (
         SET MyLog=%3
   ) 
SET MyLogFile=%MyLog%\ServiceRestart%MyTimeStamp%.log
ECHO.
ECHO. >> %MyLogFile%
ECHO ------------- ------------- %MyHours%:%MyMinutes%:%MySeconds%.%MyHundredths% %MyMonth%/%MyDay%/%MyCentury% ------------- ------------- 
ECHO ------------- ------------- %MyHours%:%MyMinutes%:%MySeconds%.%MyHundredths% %MyMonth%/%MyDay%/%MyCentury% ------------- ------------- >> %MyLogFile% 
ECHO Begin batch program %0. 
ECHO Begin batch program %0. >> %MyLogFile%
ECHO Logging to file %MyLogFile%. 
ECHO Logging to file %MyLogFile%. >> %MyLogFile% 
ECHO Attempting to restart service %2 on computer %1.
ECHO Attempting to restart service %2 on computer %1. >> %MyLogFile%

PING -n 1 %1 | FIND "TTL=" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 1 IF NOT errorlevel 2 GOTO SystemOffline
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "FAILED 1060" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO InvalidServiceName
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 1 IF NOT errorlevel 2 GOTO SystemOffline

:ResolveInitialState
SET /A MyDelay+=1
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "RUNNING" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO StopService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "STOPPED" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO StartService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "PAUSED" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO SystemOffline
ECHO Service State is changing, waiting %MyDelay% seconds for service to resolve its state before making changes.
ECHO Service State is changing, waiting %MyDelay% seconds for service to resolve its state before making changes. >> %MyLogFile%
TIMEOUT /t %MyDelay% /nobreak >> %MyLogFile%
GOTO ResolveInitialState

:StopService
SET /A MyDelay=0
ECHO Stopping %2 on \\%1.
ECHO Stopping %2 on \\%1. >> %MyLogFile%
SC \\%1 stop %2 | FIND "FAILED" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO Unstoppable

:StoppingServiceDelay
SET /A MyDelay+=1
IF %MyDelay%==21 GOTO MaybeUnStoppable
ECHO Waiting %MyDelay% seconds for %2 to stop.
ECHO Waiting %MyDelay% seconds for %2 to stop. >> %MyLogFile%
TIMEOUT /t %MyDelay% /nobreak >> %MyLogFile%
:StoppingService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "STOPPED" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO StoppedService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "STOP_PENDING" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO StoppingServiceDelay
GOTO StoppingServiceDelay

:MaybeUnStoppable
:: If we got here we waited approximately 3 mintues and the service has not stopped.
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "NOT_STOPPABLE" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO OneLastChance
GOTO Unstoppable 

:OneLastChance
SC \\%1 stop %2 >> %MyLogFile%
SET /A MyDelay+=1
ECHO Waiting %MyDelay% seconds for %2 to stop.
ECHO Waiting %MyDelay% seconds for %2 to stop. >> %MyLogFile%
TIMEOUT /t %MyDelay% /nobreak >> %MyLogFile%
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "STOPPED" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO StoppedService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "RUNNING" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 1 IF NOT errorlevel 2 GOTO UnknownState
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "NOT_STOPPABLE" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO Unstoppable
GOTO StoppingServiceDelay

:StoppedService
ECHO %2 on \\%1 is stopped.
ECHO %2 on \\%1 is stopped. >> %MyLogFile%
GOTO StartService

:StartService
SET /A MyDelay=0 
ECHO Starting %2 on \\%1.
ECHO Starting %2 on \\%1. >> %MyLogFile%
SC \\%1 start %2 >> %MyLogFile%

GOTO StartingService
:StartingServiceDelay
SET /A MyDelay+=1
ECHO Waiting %MyDelay% seconds for %2 to start.
ECHO Waiting %MyDelay% seconds for %2 to start. >> %MyLogFile%
TIMEOUT /t %MyDelay% /nobreak >> %MyLogFile%
:StartingService
SC \\%1 query %2 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "RUNNING" >> %MyLogFile%
IF errorlevel 1 IF NOT errorlevel 2 GOTO StartingServiceDelay

:StartedService
ECHO %2 on \\%1 is started.
ECHO %2 on \\%1 is started. >> %MyLogFile%
GOTO EndExit

:SystemOffline
ECHO Failure! Server \\%1 or service %2 is not accessible or is offline!
ECHO Failure! Server \\%1 or service %2 is not accessible or is offline! >> %MyLogFile%
ECHO See log file %MyLogFile% for details!
GOTO EndExit

:InvalidServiceName
ECHO Failure! Service %2 is not valid!
ECHO Failure! Service %2 is not valid! >> %MyLogFile%
ECHO See log file %MyLogFile% for details!
GOTO EndExit

:UnknownState
ECHO Failure! Service %2 in an unknown state and cannot be stopped!
ECHO Failure! Service %2 in an unknown state and cannot be stopped! >> %MyLogFile%
ECHO See log file %MyLogFile% for details!
GOTO EndExit

:UnStoppable
ECHO Failure! Service %2 cannot be stopped! Check dependencies or system state.
ECHO Failure! Service %2 cannot be stopped! Check dependencies or system state. >> %MyLogFile%
ECHO See log file %MyLogFile% for details!
GOTO EndExit

:Usage
ECHO Will restart a remote service, waiting for the service to stop/start (if necessary).
ECHO.
ECHO Usage:
ECHO %0 [system name] [service name] [logfile path]
ECHO Example: %0 server1 MyService C:\Temp\Log
ECHO.
GOTO EndExit

:EndExit
ECHO.
ECHO %0 Ended.
ECHO.
```

Answer (score 4):

What about PowerShell and [Restart-Service commandlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176942.aspx)? :)

```
Get-Service W3SVC -computer myserver | Restart-Service
```

Comment: Nice. Remember to run from admin-enabled shell (the error message when not elevated isn't very clear).

Comment: For Powershell 2.0 you'll have to resort to a [trick](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/10/13/powertip-use-poweshell-to-start-service-on-remote-machine.aspx): `Get-Service W3SVC -computer myserver | Set-Service -Status Stopped; Get-Service W3SVC -computer myserver | Set-Service -Status Running`.

Answer (score 2):

Eric Falsken's scripts are fantastic for this purpose. But note that they use the timeout command which is only available in Vista/Server2003 and newer. For an XP machine you can use sleep.exe from the NT Resource Kit instead. (This should be a commment to Eric's answer but not enough rep to do that).

Answer (score 2):

I improved the script of Eric Falsken and revised by Gerorge Perkins.

Changes:

- now it is not only a restart script. The script can start, stop and restart a local or remote service;
- removed logging (if you want this, you can use it simply by launching SCRIPT_NAME.bat > logfile.txt);
- sparse optimizations.

  ```
  @ECHO off
  :: This script originally authored by Eric Falsken http://stackoverflow.com/
  :: Revised by George Perkins 10/20/2011
  :: Revised by Armando Contestabile 02/23/2015
  IF "%1"=="" GOTO Usage
  IF "%2"=="" GOTO Usage

  SET ACTION=%1
  SET SERVICENAME=%2

  IF "%3"=="" (
      SET SYSTEMNAME=%COMPUTERNAME%
  ) ELSE (
      SET SYSTEMNAME=%3
  )

  IF "%ACTION%" == "stop" (
      SET ACTION=STOP
  ) ELSE IF "%ACTION%" == "STOP" (
      SET ACTION=STOP
  ) ELSE IF "%ACTION%" == "start" (
      SET ACTION=START
  ) ELSE IF "%ACTION%" == "START" (
      SET ACTION=START
  ) ELSE IF "%ACTION%" == "restart" (
      SET ACTION=RESTART
  ) ELSE IF "%ACTION%" == "RESTART" (
      SET ACTION=RESTART
  ) ELSE GOTO Usage

  SET STATE=
  SET CURRENT_STATUS=
  SET /A DEFAULT_DELAY=5
  SET /A SLEEP_COUNT=0
  SET /A RESTARTED=0
  SET /A MAX_WAIT_PERIODS=5

  ECHO.
  ECHO Attempting to %ACTION% service %SERVICENAME% on computer %SYSTEMNAME%.

  PING -n 1 %SYSTEMNAME% | FIND "TTL=" >nul 2>&1
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 2 (
      ECHO Failure! Server \\%SYSTEMNAME% or service %SERVICENAME% is not accessible or is offline!
      EXIT /B 1
  )
  SC \\%SYSTEMNAME% query %SERVICENAME% | FIND "FAILED 1060" >nul 2>&1
  IF ERRORLEVEL 0 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
      ECHO Failure! Service %SERVICENAME% is not valid!
      EXIT /B 2
  )
  SC \\%SYSTEMNAME% query %SERVICENAME% | FIND "STATE" >nul 2>&1
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 2 (
      ECHO Failure! Server \\%SYSTEMNAME% or service %SERVICENAME% is not accessible or is offline!
      EXIT /B 3
  )

  :Dispatch
  FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('SC \\%SYSTEMNAME% query %SERVICENAME% ^| FIND "STATE"') DO SET STATE=%%i

  ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"1" >nul
  IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=STOPPED
  ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"2" >nul
  IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=START_PENDING
  ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"3" >nul
  IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=STOP_PENDING
  ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"4" >nul
  IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=RUNNING
  ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"5" >nul
  IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=CONTINUE_PENDING
  ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"6" >nul
  IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=PAUSE_PENDING
  ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"7" >nul
  IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=PAUSED

  ECHO Current status of service is %CURRENT_STATUS%

  IF NOT "%CURRENT_STATUS%"=="RUNNING" IF NOT "%CURRENT_STATUS%"=="STOPPED" IF NOT "%CURRENT_STATUS%"=="PAUSED" (
      IF "%SLEEP_COUNT%"=="%MAX_WAIT_PERIODS%" (
          ECHO Service state won't change. Script exececution is canceled.
          EXIT /B 4
      )
      ECHO Service State is changing, waiting %DEFAULT_DELAY% seconds...
      SLEEP %DEFAULT_DELAY%
      SET /A SLEEP_COUNT+=1
      GOTO Dispatch
  )

  IF "%ACTION%"=="START" (
      IF "%CURRENT_STATUS%"=="RUNNING" (
          ECHO Service %SERVICENAME% is running.
          GOTO EndExit
      ) ELSE (
          GOTO StartService
      )
  ) ELSE IF "%ACTION%"=="RESTART" (
      IF "%CURRENT_STATUS%"=="RUNNING" (
          IF %RESTARTED%==1 (
              ECHO Service %SERVICENAME% restarted.
              GOTO EndExit
          )
          SET /A SLEEP_COUNT=0
          GOTO StopService
      ) ELSE (
          SET /A RESTARTED=1
          GOTO StartService
      )
  ) ELSE IF "%ACTION%"=="STOP" (
      IF "%CURRENT_STATUS%"=="STOPPED"  (
          ECHO Service %SERVICENAME% is stopped.
          GOTO EndExit
      ) ELSE (
          GOTO StopService
      )
  )

  :StartService
  ECHO Starting %SERVICENAME% on \\%SYSTEMNAME%
  SC \\%SYSTEMNAME% start %SERVICENAME% >nul 2>&1
  SET SLEEP_COUNT=0
  GOTO Dispatch

  :StopService
  ECHO Stopping %SERVICENAME% on \\%SYSTEMNAME%
  SC \\%SYSTEMNAME% stop %SERVICENAME% >nul 2>&1
  SET SLEEP_COUNT=0
  GOTO Dispatch

  :Usage
  ECHO This script can start/stop/restart a local or remote service, waiting for the service to stop/start ^(if necessary^).
  ECHO.
  ECHO Usage:
  ECHO %0 ^<start^|stop^|restart^> ^<SERVICE^> [SYSTEM]
  ECHO.
  ECHO If no SYSTEM is provided, the script attempts to execute on the local system.
  EXIT /B 5

  :EndExit
  ECHO.
  EXIT /B 0
  ```

Comment: I get "'SLEEP' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: Which Windows version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I've made a minor change to the script, so that it is running under Windows 10 or similar Versions.
The command "sleep" was replaced with the command "timeout".

```
@ECHO off
:: This script originally authored by Eric Falsken http://stackoverflow.com/
:: Revised by George Perkins 10/20/2011
:: Revised by Armando Contestabile 02/23/2015
:: Revised by Sascha Jelinek 11/13/2020
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Usage
IF "%2"=="" GOTO Usage

SET ACTION=%1
SET SERVICENAME=%2

IF "%3"=="" (
    SET SYSTEMNAME=%COMPUTERNAME%
) ELSE (
    SET SYSTEMNAME=%3
)

IF "%ACTION%" == "stop" (
    SET ACTION=STOP
) ELSE IF "%ACTION%" == "STOP" (
    SET ACTION=STOP
) ELSE IF "%ACTION%" == "start" (
    SET ACTION=START
) ELSE IF "%ACTION%" == "START" (
    SET ACTION=START
) ELSE IF "%ACTION%" == "restart" (
    SET ACTION=RESTART
) ELSE IF "%ACTION%" == "RESTART" (
    SET ACTION=RESTART
) ELSE GOTO Usage

SET STATE=
SET CURRENT_STATUS=
SET /A DEFAULT_DELAY=5
SET /A SLEEP_COUNT=0
SET /A RESTARTED=0
SET /A MAX_WAIT_PERIODS=5

ECHO.
ECHO Attempting to %ACTION% service %SERVICENAME% on computer %SYSTEMNAME%.

PING -n 1 %SYSTEMNAME% | FIND "Antwort von" >nul 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 2 (
    ECHO Failure!! Server \\%SYSTEMNAME% or service %SERVICENAME% is not accessible or is offline!
    EXIT /B 1
)
SC \\%SYSTEMNAME% query %SERVICENAME% | FIND "FAILED 1060" >nul 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO Failure! Service %SERVICENAME% is not valid!
    EXIT /B 2
)
SC \\%SYSTEMNAME% query %SERVICENAME% | FIND "STATE" >nul 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 2 (
    ECHO Failure! Server \\%SYSTEMNAME% or service %SERVICENAME% is not accessible or is offline!
    EXIT /B 3
)

:Dispatch
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('SC \\%SYSTEMNAME% query %SERVICENAME% ^| FIND "STATE"') DO SET STATE=%%i

ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"1" >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=STOPPED
ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"2" >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=START_PENDING
ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"3" >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=STOP_PENDING
ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"4" >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=RUNNING
ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"5" >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=CONTINUE_PENDING
ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"6" >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=PAUSE_PENDING
ECHO %STATE% | FINDSTR /C:"7" >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 SET CURRENT_STATUS=PAUSED

ECHO Current status of service is %CURRENT_STATUS%

IF NOT "%CURRENT_STATUS%"=="RUNNING" IF NOT "%CURRENT_STATUS%"=="STOPPED" IF NOT "%CURRENT_STATUS%"=="PAUSED" (
    IF "%SLEEP_COUNT%"=="%MAX_WAIT_PERIODS%" (
        ECHO Service state won't change. Script exececution is canceled.
        EXIT /B 4
    )
    ECHO Service State is changing, waiting %DEFAULT_DELAY% seconds...
    TIMEOUT /t %DEFAULT_DELAY% /NOBREAK
    SET /A SLEEP_COUNT+=1
    GOTO Dispatch
)

IF "%ACTION%"=="START" (
    IF "%CURRENT_STATUS%"=="RUNNING" (
        ECHO Service %SERVICENAME% is running.
        GOTO EndExit
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO StartService
    )
) ELSE IF "%ACTION%"=="RESTART" (
    IF "%CURRENT_STATUS%"=="RUNNING" (
        IF %RESTARTED%==1 (
            ECHO Service %SERVICENAME% restarted.
            GOTO EndExit
        )
        SET /A SLEEP_COUNT=0
        GOTO StopService
    ) ELSE (
        SET /A RESTARTED=1
        GOTO StartService
    )
) ELSE IF "%ACTION%"=="STOP" (
    IF "%CURRENT_STATUS%"=="STOPPED"  (
        ECHO Service %SERVICENAME% is stopped.
        GOTO EndExit
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO StopService
    )
)

:StartService
ECHO Starting %SERVICENAME% on \\%SYSTEMNAME%
SC \\%SYSTEMNAME% start %SERVICENAME% >nul 2>&1
SET SLEEP_COUNT=0
GOTO Dispatch

:StopService
ECHO Stopping %SERVICENAME% on \\%SYSTEMNAME%
SC \\%SYSTEMNAME% stop %SERVICENAME% >nul 2>&1
SET SLEEP_COUNT=0
GOTO Dispatch

:Usage
ECHO This script can start/stop/restart a local or remote service, waiting for the service to stop/start ^(if necessary^).
ECHO.
ECHO Usage:
ECHO %0 ^<start^|stop^|restart^> ^<SERVICE^> [SYSTEM]
ECHO.
ECHO If no SYSTEM is provided, the script attempts to execute on the local system.
EXIT /B 5

:EndExit
ECHO.
EXIT /B 0
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>NET START  and NET STOP  shouldn't return until the service has indicated that the service has started or stopped successfully.</strike>

Comment: I can confirm that they do return *before* the service has stopped when killing it remotely.  I do this several times a day.

Comment: Interesting.  I thought they waited until the service had indicated a SERVICE_STARTED or SERVICE_STOPPED code back to the SCM.

Comment: Let me clear up that previous comment.  In my experience Windows may *think* that the service is stopped but in reality it is still tearing down.  I don't know if this is because of a misbehaving service or this is business as usual.  I have run into it more than once.  I would not count on the service being immediately torn down after a stop, and for sure would not count on the service being open for business immediately after a start.

Comment: The service can tell Windows whatever it wants; it can delay execution after it has told Windows it has "started", it can do additional tear-down after telling Windows it has "stopped".  Bad form IMHO, but completely possible.

Comment: One correction: according to the documentation, once the status is set to stopped the SCM may terminate the service at any point.  In my experience this usually happens immediately, i.e., the call to SetServiceStatus simply never returns.  So any necessary tear-down needs to happen *before* the status is set to stopped.  (This might not apply when multiple services share a process, though I suspect it does when the last service is stopped.)

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can do this with a straight dos command.  You might check [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com) or other similar sites to see if there's a custom solution for this already.

If not, you could write a secondary Windows service that does this for you by exposing the start/stop functionality through a WCF endpoint.  To access this secondary service remotely, you could write a simple console app that connects to this service to start/stop the Windows service in question.  Since it's a console app, it would mimic the desired behavior of working from the command line and not returning until complete (or an error occurred).  It's not the straightforward, simple solution you're looking for, but I'll throw it out there for consideration.

Comment: That's over-killing for a task that can be resolved using a simple bat script... Remember the KISS principle..