# Tomcat service is throwing Runtime exception when stopping using JNA

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, service, jna

I am trying to stop Tomcat Service and a custom service (which i have created in windows) using JNA in my Java program. Sometimes Tomcat service takes longer time to stop.

```
 W32Service service = null;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean isStopped = false;
        try
        {
            W32ServiceManager serviceManager = new W32ServiceManager();
            serviceManager.open(Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS); 
            service = serviceManager.openService(serviceName, Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
            //service.queryStatus().dwWaitHint =  60000;
            synchronized (service) {
             service.stopService();
            }
            service.close();
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Timeout happened.");

        }finally{
            if(null != service.getHandle()){
                while(!isStopped){
                    if(service.queryStatus().dwCurrentState == Winsvc.SERVICE_STOPPED
                            || System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime >= Constants.SERVICE_STOP_WAIT_TIME){
                        isStopped=true;
                    }
                }

                if(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime >= Constants.SERVICE_STOP_WAIT_TIME){
                    System.out.println("Service Continuing.....");
                    throw new ServiceNotStoppedException("Service Not Stopped after 2 minutes");

                }else{
                    System.out.println("Service Stopped");
                    isStopped=true;
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Service Stopped.");
                isStopped=true;
            }
        }
```

In the above code, i am catching a Runtime Exception thrown which give the below message.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout waiting for service to change to a non-pending state.
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32Service.waitForNonPendingState(W32Service.java:162)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32Service.stopService(W32Service.java:98)
at com.taskkill.sample.Sample.stopService(Sample.java:32)
at com.taskkill.sample.Sample.main(Sample.java:12)
```

I have checked previous threads on similar topic but couldn't find any resolution. It is waiting for a default time and throwing error. Is there any way we can extend this time dwWaithint? (I have tried  //service.queryStatus().dwWaitHint =  60000;) but it doesn't work. Tomcat Service is eventually stopping/Hung while using this method. This works but is there a better way to handle the RunTimeException?

If i use command prompt process by the following code, it returns exit code "0" immediately, whereas the process is still stopping in the background.

```
String[] stopTomcat = { "sc", "stop", "Tomcat7" };
Process tomcatProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(stopTomcat);
```

Comment: Which version of JNA are you using? We had a problem recently cleaning/disposing native resources when JNA's native library is unloaded. This has been fixed in JNA Version 4.2 (which isn't released yet). Have a look here: https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am using JNA version 4.1.0. 4.2 doesn't give much details about the problem i am facing.

Comment: Why using JNA? Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405372/stopping-starting-a-remote-windows-service-and-waiting-for-it-to-open-close