# How to Create a Java programe through which I can run a DOS batch file remotely from client; I dont want to put batch file on server

Tags: java, windows, dos

We have client side Windows server in which we frequently observe many services going DOwn,

Now Either we have to individually Login to Server and restart Service,

But I have written A Batch file which when run can automatically Restart all the services, but teh problem is I dont want to put them in Each server, tehre are 50+ server,

how to remotely connect to those serevr and execute this batch file, I have server Credential also,

Please Reply

Comment: SHOUTING WILL NOT GET A FASTER ANSWER!  (But it might get you ignored.)

Comment: If you don't want to put the batch file in to the server, how can it execute DOS commands written in that batch in that specific server? :O

Comment: If you've got over 50 servers, you need a competent system administrator, not a way to run batch files remotely.

Comment: Not an direct answer to this, but if you have added this service as a windows service (which you can manage using Computer Management -> Service and Applications -> Services), you can set it to restart on failure by going to "Poperties" window and then "Recovery" tab.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187836/how-do-i-restart-a-service-on-a-remote-machine-in-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considered actually running your "services" as a Windows Service, so Windows will restart it automatically?

winsw - http://kenai.com/projects/winsw/pages/Home - is the one used in Glassfish for this purpose.  We've used it for other Java based services too, works nicely.

Being able to run externally submitted batch files is a security disaster just waiting to happen.  I would recommend against it.

Comment: Hello My idea is to write a JAVA code which when Run will execute Batch File or the commands in the batch file into the server and run them remotely , I think ProcessBuilder() command might help but I dont know how to Use It,     AND I am sorry if it seemed Like I am shouting Actually wanted to put everythn in title so it was easir to understand

Comment: @Manjula,The idea yjhat you suggested is not working:(:(, I put the restart option for service(Apache Tomacat) for 1 minute, i stopped it manually, and it dindt restart automatically also

Comment: @RAJ, the "and run them remotely" is the hard, insecure part which I do not think you should do that way.

Comment: ...if it is so, then is there any way, so we can create session and run this Batch file or commands using the session