# How can i use Jenkins running on Mac to restart remote Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, continuous-integration

My Tomcat is running on a remote Windows machine. The Jenkins is running of a Mac machine. I use Jenkins to deploy new jar files to the remote machine and would like to also restart Tomcat automatically. How i can do that?

Comment: Might be helpful to find out how you deploy files to the remote machine. I deploy to my AIX machines, by having them run a jenkins slave. This way I can run all the commands I need locally on the AIX machine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Tomcat is installed as a Windows Service, one possibility is to write a script to call the remote windows service to start stop the service. Keep in mind, both the Windows and mac would have to likely be on the some domain or have some explicit trust relationship. [How do I restart a service on a remote machine in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187836/how-do-i-restart-a-service-on-a-remote-machine-in-windows)

Another way is to install cygwin on the box, install sshd on windows, install ssh keys between Jenkins user on the mac and a Windows Administrator account. Then you can effectively ssh into the Windows box and run a Unix or Dos cmd to bounce Tomcat via a shell task in Jenkins. The instructions I have for doing this at my company are 10 pages long, but it is possible.