# Team City: Cannot Redeploy to Tomcat7

Tags: windows, continuous-integration, tomcat7, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I have a build configuration that uses the Team City deployer plugin.
I'm using a container deploy to deploy the war file to Tomcat.7.0.63 installed as a service on a Windows Server 2012 R2 box.
The first time I run the the build, the artifact (a war file_ deploys successfully.
The second time, and all subsequent runs, the deploy fails.

The error message:

```
Build failure message received: org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to undeploy
```

The log file error:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Unable to delete
```

When I go to the webapps folder on the remote server, the war file is deleted, but the expanded folder is only partially deleted. Most files are gone, except for a png file. 
I am not able to manually delete the folder because Tomcat still has a lock on it.
If I restart tomcat, I'm then able to run the build successfully (war file deploys).

One thought I had was to restart Tomcat before or after each deploy.
How would I restart Tomcat from TeamCity?
Or perhaps, does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Looking at the [Tomcat7 config docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html); have you tried the `antiResourceLocking` option?

Comment: I have not. I'll look into that.

Comment: @SteveChapman You're suggestion for using antiResourceLocking worked fantastically. I also added the "reloadable" option since this is an integration test server, with multiple redeploys possibly happening through the day. Create an answer with your suggestion and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad it worked; answer has been added.

Comment: FYI: found out how to remotely start/stop a service on windows. TeamCity has a command line runner which could be used to execute a .bat file with sc \\<server-name> start\stop <service-name>
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187836/how-do-i-restart-a-service-on-a-remote-machine-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the Tomcat Context using the `antiResourceLocking` option, as detailed further in the [online documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).  This does come with some trade-offs however; definitely worth reading the documentation in full and evaluating if it's a suitable option for your application.

Comment: What are your thoughts on using this in production? I found that if I just wait about five minutes (more than enough time for the application to finish loading in Tomcat), then I can run the TeamCity deploy again without using this parameter. So for production, it might not be needed, but since this is integration testing, and I might have impatient testers hitting that "Run" button, I decided to make it fault tolerant.