# How stop a service and its dependencies via cmd with java?

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, automation

I tested with net stop \\ComputerName "NPS Index", but displays:

> The syntax of this command is:
>   NET STOP
>   service

The service has dependencies.
The java code is:

```
private static void stopService(String server, String serviceName) {
    try {
//            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "sc", "\\\\" + server, "stop", serviceName);
//            Process process = builder.start();
//            process.waitFor();
        String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "net", "\\\\" + server, "stop" , serviceName};
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
        InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error to execute commands line in cmd " + e);
    }
}
```

please, somebody could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to stop a service on a remote computer?

In this case the syntax is

```
sc \\machine stop <service>
```

(see [How do I restart a service on a remote machine in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187836/how-do-i-restart-a-service-on-a-remote-machine-in-windows))

You can list the service dependencies with the `--EnumDepend` flag.

Comment: I need restart its dependent services. Is there any parameter for sc to include its dependent services?

Comment: The command line would:
sc \\machine stop "NPS Index" --EnumDepend, to restart the service and its dependencies?

I tested, but the message "The parameter is incorrect" is displayed in cmd